# How to handle null values inside my sort by function?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a React table that has sortable headers by desc and asc values.
It parses string values to numbers for sorting. However, my `numeric(x)` function fails to deliver when it meets a `null` value in my dataset.

Here is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null`

Below is my function, and I also added code on how I implement `numeric` to my `Comparator()` for sorting

```
function numeric(x) {
    const val = parseFloat(x);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
      return parseFloat(x.slice(1));
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  }

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
{
    const numericA = numeric(a[orderBy]);
    const numericB = numeric(b[orderBy]);
    if (numericB < numericA){
        return -1
    }
    if (numericB > numericA){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

How should I handle nulls in my numeric function? Realistically, they should be ignored and be placed at the bottom of the pecking order when sorting by asc and desc.

EDIT:
example data types for input x:

- 10
- 10%
- $10
- .1
- abc (string characters)

If not careful, the Null values can act as a `0` when sorting data. It's important to note that Null simply means no data available, they should not be given a numerical value.

EDIT EDIT:
Important information about my Comparator and sorting functions

```
function getComparator(order, orderBy)
{
    return order === "desc" 
        ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
        : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
}

const sortedRowInformation = (rowArray, comparator) =>
{
    const stabilizedRowArray = rowArray.map((el, index) => [el, index])
    stabilizedRowArray.sort((a, b) =>
    {
        const order = comparator(a[0], b[0])
        if (order !== 0) return order
        return a[1] - b[1]
    })
    return stabilizedRowArray.map((el) => el[0])
}
```

An example of my table that uses all of these functions pieced together:

```
export default function TableContent(props)
{
    const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection] = useState('asc');
    const [valueToOrderBy, setValueToOrderBy] = useState('symbol');

    const { data } = props;
    
    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) =>
    {
        const isAscending = (valueToOrderBy === property && orderDirection === 'asc') 
        setValueToOrderBy(property)
        setOrderDirection(isAscending ? 'desc' : 'asc')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <TableContainer>
                <Table>
                    <AdvancedStatsHeaders
                        data={data}
                        valueToOrderBy={valueToOrderBy}
                        orderDirection={orderDirection}
                        handleRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                    />
                    <TableBody>
                    {
                        sortedRowInformation(data, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy))
                            .map((stock, index) => (
                            <TableRow key = {index} >
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.symbol}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.enterprisevalue}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.enterprise_value_revenue}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.revenuepershare}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.debt_to_equity}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.ebitda}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.profitmargin}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.price_to_sales}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.price_to_book}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {stock.put_call_ratio}
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))
                    }
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </>
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing that slice, but one way of avoiding this specific error is to do something like this:   `if (x && isNaN(val))`.  Or you can have a try-catch block.

Comment: @HåkenLid, I'm not sure what to return after that statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The challenge is about sorting numbers OR text with the same function, based on a column name and a direction. The difficulty is about making sure we deal with a number or with text... to apply the right `.sort()` callback.

Additionally, there are two *things* to take in account:

- Some strings may need to be "reformatted" as numbers
- Some values may be `null` and should always must ends up at the end of the sorting.

---

Okay! First, let's go through your functions from the first one:

```
sortedRowInformation(data, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy)).map(...)
```

That `sortedRowInformation` really looks like a `.sort()` function nested in a `.sort()` function... With two `.map()` applied on a `stabilizedRowArray` sub-array...

***I have to admit I discarded it right away***. I assumed the expected result by its pretty descriptive name and the 1st argument being the `data`.

The second argument... Where `getComparator()` is a function call with the two componant state properties as argument. That returns two possible functions (lol, the same function with or without a minus sign in front of its evaluation...). So calling that `descendingComparator` function again calls another function `numeric()` where our `null` problem is.

And all this process to just return `-1`, `0` or `1` to be used as that second argument for `sortedRowInformation()`... Which is the basic `.sort()` internal job.

**Just describing this process should raise a big flag. You nicely overcomplicated everything.**

---

## Solution

Here are my solution explanations starting from the other end:

The `numeric()` function is okay to isolate as a function. But that is where you had difficulties due to the `null` values coming in 3 functions above... So what if we put the `null` values aside from that logic and always assume a non-null value?

So now that we decided there is no `null` values, we can test them more easily for number or string. Anyway there is a special case where a string can finally be a number when removing the `$` and comas (thousand separator).

I came up with this custom `isNumeric()` function:

```
function isNumeric(x) {
  let value = !isNaN(x) ? x: parseFloat(x.replace(/[\$,]/g, ""))
  return {isNum:!isNaN(value), value}
}
```

That function returns an object containing a boolean and a "processed" value: a number or `NaN`.

Now... Getting back to the starting point for the sorting, here is a function to sort the `data`:

```
function sortAll(data, orderDirection, valueToOrderBy) {
  
  // Filter the nulls in an array and the rest in another
  let nulls = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy] == null)
  let toSort = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy])
  
  // Sort the non-null values
  let sorted = toSort.sort((a, b) => {
    
    // Check if both values are numeric
    let aa = isNumeric(a[valueToOrderBy])
    let bb = isNumeric(b[valueToOrderBy])
    
    // If numerics
    if (aa.isNum && bb.isNum) {
      return aa.value - bb.value
    }
    
    // If strings
    return (a[valueToOrderBy]).toLowerCase() > (b[valueToOrderBy]).toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
  });

  // The sorting direction
  if (orderDirection === "desc") {
    sorted.reverse();
  }
  
  //  Add the nulls at the end of the returned array
  return sorted.concat(nulls);
}
```

So to apply it in your React component return is:

```
sortAll(data, orderDirection, valueToOrderBy).map(...)
```

instead of:

```
sortedRowInformation(data, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy)).map(...)
```

Squarely discard those functions: `sortedRowInformation` , `getComparator` and `descendingComparator` and replace `numeric` with my `isNumeric`.

Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yLVKxyB?editors=0011) where I tested the sorting cases with some feak `data`.

---

If it does not already work in all cases with your `data`... At least, it is way easier to improve. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what's your sorting function is. `Array.prototype.sort()` expects `Comparator` in the form of

```
function Comparator(a, b, /* no `orderBy` here! */) { ... }
```

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters)

and passes **items** of an array in `a` and `b`, not two references to the same array. So the code your've wrote in this question looks wrong.

But maybe that's just a copy-paste error, so let's assume that your're using the standard `Array.prototype.sort()`. In this case

```js
if( a === null ) return 1
if( b === null ) return -1
```

should do the trick:

```js
function numeric(x) {
    const val = parseFloat(x);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
      return parseFloat(x.slice(1));
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  }

function descendingComparator(a, b) // removed `orderBy`
{
    if( a === null ) return 1
    if( b === null ) return -1
    const numericA = numeric(a); // removed [orderBy]
    const numericB = numeric(b); // removed [orderBy]
    if (numericB < numericA){
        return -1
    }
    if (numericB > numericA){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

const test_arr = [null, 1, null, '3%', 0, '2', "$4", null]

console.log([...test_arr].sort(descendingComparator))

// here's how you can implement behavior of removed `orderBy` arg
const ascendingComparator = (a, b) => descendingComparator(b, a)

console.log([...test_arr].sort(ascendingComparator))
// or simply use `reverse()`

// or, if you want `null` at the and in this case too, then
const ascendingComparator2 = (a, b) => {
    if( a === null ) return 1
    if( b === null ) return -1
    return descendingComparator(b, a)
}

console.log([...test_arr].sort(ascendingComparator2))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the snippet, looks clear. When I don't add the orderBy in the descendingComparator, I get `
TypeError: x.slice is not a function` ? I also added more code in my post to make things a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
function numeric(x,order) {
    const val = parseFloat(x);
    if(!x) {
     return order === 'desc'? -1 : 1;
    }
    else {
     if (isNaN(val)) {
       return parseFloat(x.slice(1));
      } else {
       return val;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Prabhakar, when I do this, the null value is being treated as a value of 0, which is setting the orderBy in between other positive and negative values.